# How does creating two instances of Tk work with one mainloop?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

How does adding `master = Tk()` into the `__init__` of a subclass of tkinter.Frame
produce two windows (`app` and `app2`) when only `app.mainloop()` is called?

```
from tkinter import Frame,Button,Tk

class Application(Frame):

    def say_hi(self):
        print('Hello world?!')

    def close(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quit_b = Button(self, width=12, text='Quit', bg='tan',
                    command=self.close)
        self.quit_b.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=8, pady=8)

        self.hello_b = Button(self, width=12, text='Hello',
                    command=self.say_hi)
        self.hello_b.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=8, pady=8)

    def __init__(self):
        master = Tk() # <------------------------ ! see here !
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()


app = Application()
app.master.title('Hello world!')

app2 = Application()
app2.master.title('Hello world! 2')

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create two instances of the class `Tk`, and it's somewhat unusual to instantiate it within the `__init__` of another class. Your code should work, but I've never seen it done that way.

You need to create an instance of `Tk` before creating any other widgets. Since your main app is a subclass of `Frame`, you're partially creating the instance of a `Frame` before initializing Tkinter which is simply not the way it should be done. It might work, but the behavior is undefined.

Instead, it's generally better to create your application as a subclass of Tk:

```
from Tkinter import tk
class Application(tk.Tk):
    ...

app = Application(...)
app.mainloop()
```

OR, create an instance of `Tk` at the global scope, and pass it as an argument to your other widgets:

```
from Tkinter import tk
class Application(tkFrame):
    ...
root = tk.Tk()
myframe = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If you need more than one window, create additional windows with the `Toplevel` class.

Comment: @HonestAbe: Because you created an instance of `Tk` in the constructor of `Application`, and created two instances of `Application`, you're getting two instances of Tkinter. There's simply no reason to do it and will yield unexpected results (obviously, since what is happening is not what you expect).

Comment: I cleaned up the question a bit and removed my old comments on this answer. Could you edit this answer to clarify: "You cannot create two instances of the class Tk...". Are you saying that the `master = Tk()` in `app2` replaces the one created in `app`? And then could you explain why app.mainloop() works for both? Thanks!

Comment: @HonestAbe: `mainloop` does not create any windows, it is a simple event loop. Each time you call `Tk()` it creates a window and initializes the tk subsystem. This initialization is not designed to be done twice for one applications.

Comment: It's not a big deal but... it turns out that using `tk` as an alias prevented code completion at the method level (using PyScripter). In other words, if I typed `self.myEntry.` no box would appear with the list of Entry methods. Maybe this has something to do with the fact that the `Tk` or `BaseWidget` class has a `self.tk`. When I changed the alias to `tki` it resolved this issue. Thanks again for all your help around here.